# Converting complex SQL select to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and trying to support an existing application that is in Laravel 5.  I am trying to convert the following SQL to eloquent structure

```
SELECT s.id, 
CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) AS user_name, 
u.avatar_location AS user_img, 
s.employee_photo, 
d.name AS department, 
seg.name AS segment, 
s.survey_title, 
s.before_action, 
s.before_picture, 
s.action, 
s.action_date, 
s.after_action, 
s.after_picture, 
s.nominated, 
s.awarded, 
s.created_at, 
s.updated_at,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM likes l WHERE l.survey_id = s.id) AS likes,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM likes l WHERE l.survey_id = s.id AND l.user_id = 5) AS UserLikes,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM comments c WHERE c.survey_id = s.id ) AS comments
FROM surveys s 
JOIN departments d 
ON s.department = d.id 
JOIN segments seg 
ON s.segment_id = seg.id 
JOIN users u 
ON s.user_id = u.id 
WHERE s.status = 'Approved' 
ORDER BY s.action_date DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20
```

I know enough Laravel to know that my basic start would probably be

```
$surveys = DB::table('surveys')
    ->join('departments',  'surveys.department', '=', 'departments.id')
    ->join('segments', 'surveys.segment_id', '=', 'segments.id')
    ->join('users', 'surveys.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('surveys.status', 'Approved')
    ->orderBy('surveys.action_date')
    ->skip(20)-take(20)
    ->select(...)->get();
```

However, I am not sure how to do the subqueries.  Looking for any suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For select statements, you can use DB::raw().

```
$surveys = DB::table('surveys')
    ->join('departments',  'surveys.department', '=', 'departments.id')
    ->join('segments', 'surveys.segment_id', '=', 'segments.id')
    ->join('users', 'surveys.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('surveys.status', 'Approved')
    ->orderBy('surveys.action_date')
    ->skip(20)-take(20)
    ->select([DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM likes l WHERE l.survey_id = s.id) AS likes'),
    ...
    ])
    ->get();
```

Similarly, select statements would go under the select array. Just so to be clear, the result will be a collection.